# What's the low-down on MariaDB JSON support?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json

Does MariaDB ever plan to have full JSON support or is it just going to be an [alias](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/) forever?

It's a bummer to set constraints definition in the table just to make it work properly. Application-level migration libraries (like Phinx) doesn't support it so you have to do extra work which defeats the purpose of migration libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No plans that I know about.

Regarding constraints, I assume you mean for JSON validation: See [Changes and Improvements in MariaDB 10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-104/):

> The JSON_VALID function is automatically used as a CHECK constraint
>   for the JSON data type alias in order to ensure that a valid json
>   document is inserted (MDEV-13916)

... so you don't have to set the constraint explicitly.